# state-of-the-art of dimensionality algorithms

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, dimensions

We know there are algorithms to reduce the dimension of data sets like PCA and Isomap

- What is the state of the art in the
  reducing dimensionality to data sets.
- Do you have an example, maybe on MATLAB?

Lets say we have a data set with 100,000 attributes  like [Dorothea Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dorothea) 
(Chemical compounds represented by structural molecular features must be classified as active (binding to thrombin) or inactive. This is one of 5 datasets of the NIPS 2003 feature selection challenge.)

```
Data Set Characteristics:   Multivariate

Number of Instances:        1950

Area:                       Life

Attribute Characteristics:  Integer

Number of Attributes:       100000

Date Donated                2008-02-29

Associated Tasks:           Classification

Missing Values?             N/A

Number of Web Hits:         17103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to Matlab, you can take some ideas from the manual of their [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/stats/stats.pdf).

Look for the Feature Selection and Feature Transformation sections. Also, I would try SVD, FastMap and RobustMap. You'll need to read a bit about each and decide which one is most suitable for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum Variance Unfolding is a particularly popular technique these days.  A similar approach called Structure Preserving Embedding got best paper at ICML 2009.  A few other techniques include Laplacian Eigenmaps, Locally Linear Embedding, and Kernel PCA.